# Can any one provide me one simple example: Where we would use Kotlin data classes in android development?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As a new learner in Kotlin i am unable to understand where we would use data class, like in Android development.

I know that **Data classes** in Kotlin are classes whose main purpose is to hold data.

According to [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-data-class) it said that, **For eg:** If we want to create a *User entry* in Java using class, it require lots of boilerplate code.

*but* the same code can be written in ***single line*** using data class, which saves the developers time.

Now recently i was trying to develop an app, where i made use of ***RecyclerView***. So in a RecyclerView, you often need to create a **Java class** to represent the data that will be displayed in the list.

Below is my **Java class**

```
package com.example.project2;

import android.net.Uri;

public class HandlerRecyclerViewClass_DONAR {

String foodCount;
String restaurant;
String username;
Uri image;
String order;

public HandlerRecyclerViewClass_DONAR(String order,Uri image, String foodCount, String restaurant, String username) {
    this.order = order;
    this.foodCount = foodCount;
    this.restaurant = restaurant;
    this.username = username;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public Uri getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getRestaurant() {
    return restaurant;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getFoodCount() {
    return foodCount;
}
}
```

Now i thought that why not make use of **Data class** here and reduce the code.

Below is my **Kotlin file**

```
package com.example.project2

import android.net.Uri

data class HandlerRecyclerViewClass_DONAR_KOTLIN(
 val order:String,
 val image:Uri,
 val foodCount:String,
 val restaurant:String,
 val userName:String
)
```

**Note**: Above was just a simple example that came in my mind to reduce code by using kotlins data classes.

**Question**:
Can someone tell me that whatever i did is the correct way of using the Data classes.
Or there is more to it that i am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually the best example on why to use data classes. Data classes provide automatic implementations of `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `toString()` and similar methods. You didn't use any of these above, you only used general features of Kotlin. As a matter of fact, you can remove `data` from your code and it will work the same.

However, if we implement classes specifically for storing the data, we very often need these above methods. We would like to easily print the contents for debugging purposes, we need to compare if two objects hold the same data, we need to look for unique data, we use a map where keys consist of multiple values, etc.

In Java, we usually generate such boilerplate code by IDE. Then we have to keep it in the repository, maintain it, remember to update if anything changes, etc. In Kotlin we simply mark a class as `data` and it solves the same problem.

Comment: Ohh in my adapter class i made use of componentN() functions, Also using data class i will be able to destructure an object into a number of variables concisely right ?. So i made use of data class making to more readable

Comment: Yes, if you use destructuring then data classes provide you this feature as well. Also, `copy()`. But getters, setters and constructors aren't provided by data classes, but by other functionality of Kotlin.